# Focus issue in scroll edit text openlaszlo

Tags: openlaszlo, lzx

I am having a problem with scrolledittext in DHTMl runtime I am using firefox 16.0 I have this following code when i run this and trigger the onfocus event the whole text is getting selected.Any idea why?

I am using Openlaszlo 5.0

```
<canvas>
<include href="incubator/scrolledittext.lzx" /> 
<include href="lz/vscrollbar.lzx"/>
<include href="incubator/newvscrollbar.lzx"/>
<include href="incubator/newvscrollbar_resources.lzx"/>

           <button name="text">
           <handler name="onclick">
            canvas.sp.inp.onfocus.sendEvent();

           </handler>
           </button>
  <scrolledittext name="sp" x="50" y="50" 
                                 height="300" 
                                 width="400" 
                                 focusable="true"
                >


           </scrolledittext>


</canvas>
```